# Particles in motion

Tags: vectors, kinematics, projectile-motion

If a particle is travelling at a velocity of $v = (11 \hat{i} + 10\hat{j}) \frac m s$, and undergoing constant acceleration $a = (-1.20\hat{i} + 0.30\hat{j}) \frac m {s^2}$, in what direction is it moving? I have been trying all day to get this. I've worked out that the particle crosses the $y$-axis ($x=0$) when $t = 18s$ with the $y$-coordinate at that time being $y=230m$, travelling $19 \frac m s$... I just can't work out what direction it it is moving (anticlockwise from the positive $x$-axis).

Comment: What is its position at time $t=0$?

Comment: In all honesty, I am not sure.

Comment: But the basic idea is to solve for $\dot x$ and $\dot y$. Those are the components of the velocity in the $x$-direction and the $y$-direction. If you want the direction as an angle $\theta$ to the $x$-axis then $\frac{\dot y}{\dot x}$ gives $\tan\theta$.

Comment: Clearly it is steadily accelerating along $y$, while along $x$ will reach a maximum and then travel backwards.

Comment: Yes, but if t = 0s, then I cant use the equation of motion s = u*t + 1/2*a*t^2 as it all cancels to zero, and I dont think v^2 = u^2 + 2*a*s works either.

Comment: I got 55 degrees which i thought was right earlier, but my checker says its not.

Comment: At $t=0$ it is just moving in the direction of $v$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the initial velocity is $v = (11 \hat{i} + 10\hat{j}) \frac m s$, and the acceleration $a = (-1.20\hat{i} + 0.30\hat{j}) \frac m {s^2}$. Then, the velocity dependent on time is
$$v=v_0+at=((11-1.20t)\hat{i},(10+0.3t)\hat{j})$$
The direction will depend then on time. For example, the angle with respect to the $x-axis$ can be determined as
$$\theta=\mbox{atan}\left(\frac{v_y}{v_x}\right)=\mbox{atan}\left(\frac{10+0.3t}{11-1.20t}\right)$$
I hope it will be useful!

Answer (score 0):

x=11t+C
   Since x=0 @ t=18 => 0=11*18+C => C=-198 => x=11t-198

y=10t+C1
   Since y=230 @ t=18 => 230=10*18+C1 => C1=50 => y=10t+50

θ(anticlockwise)= arctan2 ((10t+50)/(11t-198)) Let t=0 => approximately 143 deg

θ(anticlockwise)= arctan2 ((10t+50)/(11t-198)) Let t=1 => approximately 139 deg
     https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2

Therefore, the direction would be clockwise.

I am confused on how the object can travel at 19 m/s at y=230m when your velocity in the y direction is at 10 m/s. I am having a hard time understanding the problem in that case. Hope this helps out enough with the problem.

Comment: What do you mean, "therefore the direction would be clockwise"?

Comment: The arctan2 function is a neat function where the angle theta is measured anticlockwise from your origin to positive x axis ranging from [0,360] degrees. So if you were at 90 degrees you'd be at the positive y axis, 180 degrees you'd be at the negative x axis. Since you go from 143 deg you are more close to the negative x axis in the second quadrant than at 139 degrees. Therefore, you must be moving clockwise.

Comment: If you don't like the atan2 method I can show you how to do it with arccos. It's used more often in 3d cases and not 2d.

Comment: Also if an object has constant velocity it would have an acceleration of 0.

Answer (score 0):

My partner got the answer θ = 125.36, rounding up to 130 when considering two significant figures. This answer is correct. Not sure how he got it lol, but figured I would post the correct answer :).